# AVG in a SUM statement

Tags: sql, sum, grouping, average

In SQL, the following does not work.

```
SELECT SUM(
   SELECT AVG(2)
)
```

-- And neither do this:

```
SELECT SUM(
AVG(2)
)
```

The output I expected would obviously just be 2.
Does anyone know how to work around this?

Comment: 1) tag your database , 2) provide sample data and desired output

Comment: @eshirvana What do you mean with tag your database?

Comment: You need to have a review of Stack Overflow's [Question asking guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't imagine what your are trying to do but this works:

```
SELECT SUM(a)
FROM (SELECT AVG(2) AS a) AS b
```